# Show popup after some seconds...

Tags: javascript, popup, intervals

I am using a simple popup for my site , Here's the below code, I want to show the popup after some interval of seconds,

Please help

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function(){
var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);

$('.popup').show();
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();

return false;
});

$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What you're probably looking for is javascript's setTimeout() function. As a friendly aside, you may want to get into the habit of formatting your code with proper indents - it's hard to read the structure as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the line that shows your popup in a setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.popup').show();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: One more thing, How can i disable that popup on mobile devices, using Javascript...

Comment: You should add this "one more thing" as a new question ;).

Comment: @Naftali, You are right at your side, but its fyn to put here

Comment: fetch the window size of the device and put a condition like if sceen size is less whatever dont show popup....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method, e.g.:

```
$('.popup').delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/54pzpfp1/